# How to mount a dd-image which was created via fmem (memory dump tool)

Tags: mount, memory, dump

I've used the tool `fmem` for creating a memory dump dd-file. That works fine.

But how can I access this image? I've tried it with `mount` but it says I have to specify a filesystem. But non of the given possibilities works (ext4, vfat etc).

Comment: What does the command `file dd-file` say about this file? Also try `tune2fs -l dd-file` as well as `fdisk -l dd-file`.

Comment: I would try `sudo mount -o loop -t auto dd-file /mnt`.

Answer (score 2):

`fmem` is a *memory snapshotting tool*. It creates an image of the contents of RAM.

While this may be useful for forensics or low-level debugging, it is not a filesystem image and cannot be mounted by any means.

Answer (score 2):

In trying this out myself this file is not anything other than a raw data dump/snapshot of memory. So you can examine it using any hex editor or a tool such as `hexdump`, or an appropriate forensic analysis tool.

#### Downloading and compiling

I found the latest version of `fmem` here:

- http://hysteria.sk/~niekt0/foriana/

After unpacking it you can compile it like so:

```
$ make
rm -f *.o *.ko *.mod.c Module.symvers Module.markers modules.order \.*.o.cmd \.*.ko.cmd \.*.o.d
rm -rf \.tmp_versions
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.14.4-100.fc19.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /home/saml/Downloads/fmem/fmem_1.6-0/lkm.o
  LD [M]  /home/saml/Downloads/fmem/fmem_1.6-0/fmem.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/saml/Downloads/fmem/fmem_1.6-0/fmem.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/saml/Downloads/fmem/fmem_1.6-0/fmem.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.14.4-100.fc19.x86_64'
```

To load the `fmem` kernel module you can run the included `run.sh` script with the archive:

```
$ sudo ./run.sh 
Module: insmod fmem.ko a1=0xffffffff81090ca0 : OK
Device: /dev/fmem
----Memory areas: -----
reg01: base=0x000000000 (    0MB), size= 2048MB, count=1: write-back
reg02: base=0x080000000 ( 2048MB), size= 1024MB, count=1: write-back
reg03: base=0x100000000 ( 4096MB), size= 4096MB, count=1: write-back
reg04: base=0x200000000 ( 8192MB), size= 1024MB, count=1: write-back
reg05: base=0x23c000000 ( 9152MB), size=   64MB, count=1: uncachable
reg06: base=0x0bc000000 ( 3008MB), size=   64MB, count=1: uncachable
-----------------------
!!! Don't forget add "count=" to dd !!!
```

You can then collect ~10MB of data, into file `tst.dd`:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/fmem of=tst.dd bs=1MB count=10
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
10000000 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.0541226 s, 185 MB/s
```

#### Examining the resulting file

If we throw the typical gamut of tools at this file you'll see that it doesn't contain anything other than raw binary data.

*file*

```
$ file tst.dd 
tst.dd: data
```

*fdisk*

```
$ fdisk -l tst.dd

Disk tst.dd: 9 MB, 9999872 bytes, 19531 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

*hexdump*

```
$ hexdump -C tst.dd  | head -10
00000000  53 ff 00 f0 53 ff 00 f0  c3 e2 00 f0 53 ff 00 f0  |S...S.......S...|
00000010  53 ff 00 f0 54 ff 00 f0  c9 a3 00 f0 53 ff 00 f0  |S...T.......S...|
00000020  a5 fe 00 f0 87 e9 00 f0  9f 11 00 f0 9f 11 00 f0  |................|
00000030  9f 11 00 f0 9f 11 00 f0  57 ef 00 f0 49 f5 00 f0  |........W...I...|
00000040  14 00 00 c0 4d f8 00 f0  41 f8 00 f0 9f c7 71 e1  |....M...A.....q.|
00000050  39 e7 00 f0 59 f8 00 f0  99 66 71 e1 d2 ef 00 f0  |9...Y....fq.....|
00000060  57 ff 00 f0 f2 e6 00 f0  6e fe 00 f0 53 ff 00 f0  |W.......n...S...|
00000070  53 ff 00 f0 a4 f0 00 f0  c7 ef 00 f0 01 9b 00 c0  |S...............|
00000080  9f 11 00 f0 9f 11 00 f0  9f 11 00 f0 9f 11 00 f0  |................|
```

*tune2fs*

```
$ tune2fs -l tst.dd 
tune2fs 1.42.7 (21-Jan-2013)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open tst.dd
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

*mount*

```
$ sudo mount -o loop -t auto tst.dd /mnt/
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

*dmesg*

```
[332140.394396] fmem init_module 449: init
[332140.394401] fmem find_symbols 439: set guess_page_is_ram: ffffffff81090ca0
[333010.390836] loop: module loaded
```

If you want to find out more about the category of tools that can dump memory similarly to `fmem` take a look at the list of resources in the references section.

#### So then what can I do with the dump files from fmem?

I found this article which discusses the creation *AND* analysis of these files. It's in the following article titled: [Tracing Clues: Memory Analysis - Admin Network & Security Magazine](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Forensic-Analysis-on-Linux). The article mentions 2 tools, [Draugr](https://code.google.com/p/draugr/) & [Volatilitux](https://code.google.com/p/volatilitux/).

*excerpts*

> #### Draugr
>
> One of the first tools for memory analysis on Linux was the Python script Draugr. The Draugr script allows users to investigate the memory of a running system directly via the `/dev/mem` pseudodevice. However, Draugr also analyzes memory dumps available in files. A disadvantage of Draugr is its limited functionality, which is restricted to listing processes and extracting specific memory areas. Development on Draugr stopped in 2009.
>
> #### Volatilitux
>
> Another memory analysis tool is Volatilitux, which was long heralded as the Linux equivalent to the [Volatility tool used on Windows systems](http://www.volatilesystems.com/default/volatility). The Volatility Analysis Framework now has built-in Linux support, which I will describe later in this article. Volatility has the biggest feature scope of the available Linux RAM analysis tools; however, it is worth noting that Volatility lacks two important features found in Volatilitux.
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> In addition to the functions known from Draugr, Volatilitux lets you view and extract the open files of a process. A new release in December 2011 added 64-bit support.

**NOTE:** The Windows tool, [Volatility](http://www.volatilesystems.com/default/volatility) can also be used to analyze the output of `fmem` files!

#### References

- [Tools:Memory Imaging - Wikipedia](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Memory_Imaging)
- [How do I dump physical memory in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/164960/how-do-i-dump-physical-memory-in-linux)

Comment: The bit from `hexdump` really looks like the original BIOS/UEFI IDT vectors (before switch to protected mode, seems to all point to 0x00f0XXXX addresses which would be consistent with real-mode environment) anyway.